# In UWP can we dynamically compile and invoke new Page in UWP using Dynamic compilation and member invocation using C# Reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, uwp, dynamic-compilation

Using **System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider** I can able to compile codes till .Net 4+. So I can dynamically compile the code in runtime and invoke any WinFrom forms using **C# Reflection** programmatically.
Similarly can we do that in UWP platform? I tried the same flow with UWP, but those compiler assemblies are not supported in UWP.

Comment: Why? Really curious.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **Probably not**

Why?

UWP is **sandboxed** so it would be a bit of a risk to allow dynamic code compilation, because then the app could potentially do something it's not supposed to, while making it harder for the automated scans in the store to detect malicious behaviour.

However, depending on what you actually need this for, you could always use the `System.Expression` namespace (see: [here](https://www.infoq.com/articles/expression-compiler)) to compile certain pieces of functionality on the fly.

You could then have an all-purpose page, that you just substitute functionality in and out of.